# How to start a new Activity from a CustomView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-custom-view

Usually you would start an activity with something like the following:

```
private void llMenuSettings_Click() {
     this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
               Intent intent = new Intent(XXXXXXXX.this, View_Settings.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               XXXXXXXX.this.finish();
          }
     });
}
```

However I am extending a LinearLayout:

```
public class MenuContainer extends LinearLayout {
}
```

Therefore I have run into a couple of issues:

1. How would you know what XXXXXXXX is in the example as the LinearLayout can be included in multiple Layouts?
2. startActivity() does not exist in a LinearLayout class?

There are a few similar questions but none that fully answer the above scenario therefore hoping this can be answered and help others in the future?

Comment: you mean to say want to start activity from your custom linearlayout?

Comment: Yes that is the aim :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `LinearLayout` extending class, you could create the following method:

```
public void launch() {

    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), YourActivity.class);
    getContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

Use the `getContext()` method inside your customview to retrieve the `Context` and start a new `Activity`.

Comment: Though about the same but you will never be able to call finish on the Activity.

Comment: I did try this inside of the run method but got java.lang.NullPointerException, I'll try it separated out like above...

Comment: Which run method? Just call CustomView.launch(); there is no need for runOnUIThread(...) or whatever you are using. @Steve: Why not?

Comment: Same error I'm afraid: E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at MenuContainer.runOnUiThread(MenuContainer.java:213)
            at MenuContainer.llMenuSettings_Click(MenuContainer.java:141)
            at MenuContainer.access$100(MenuContainer.java:14)
            at MenuContainer$2.onClick(MenuContainer.java:81)

Comment: You are still using runonuithread()... dont do that and post your full code as an edit to your question.

Comment: Ahhh yes that seemed to work, I assumed you had to run activity changes on the UI thread! +50000 if I could, thanks for your help :-)